# Openlayers labels overlapping

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a map with several markers that all have a label representing data at that marker point. When these markers overlap, the labels are always on top of all markers. I would like only the label for the top marker being shown. If two markers overlap right now, the label for the bottom marker still shows above the top marker. Does anyone know how to solve this problem in openlayers 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `zIndex` style property to stick labels to the marker. When working with a layer style function, the layer definition could look like this:

```js
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: '',
    // ...
  }),
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    // ...
  })
});
var styles = [style];
var index = 0;
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
    style.setZIndex(index);
    index = (index == Number.MAX_VALUE) ? 0 : index + 1;
    return styles;
  }
});
```